# Extjs menu is not scrollable with the mouse wheel in Firefox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a scrolling menu in extjs6 with the default settings, up/down buttons on top and bottom of the items list to scroll it. In Chrome and IE I am able to scroll it also with the mouse wheel.

The problem is that in Firefox the mouse wheel scrolling is not working, I am able to scroll the menu using the two buttons.

I did some test in Sencha Fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1748) and I found that the mouse wheel works fine in all browsers if I use extjs4 but it is not working in Firefox using extjs6.

There is a workaround to implement this functionality also in Firefox?
I know that Firefox is using the "DOMMouseScroll" event and not the "mousewheel" event and I tried to add this listener to the menu but it is not working.

If it is possible I prefer to use the standard menu scrolling and not the scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding scrollable property to you menu problem fixed also on firefox:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        var scrollMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            height: 100,
            scrollable:{
                x:false,
                y:true
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            scrollMenu.add({
                text: 'Item ' + (i + 1)
            });
        };

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,

            items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                width: '100%',
                height: 40,
                items: [{
                    text: 'Scrolling Menu',
                    menu: scrollMenu
                }]

            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

if you want only to fix the problem on firefox you can set this property controlling if the used browser is firefox with:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
     //Do Firefox-related activities
     scrollMenu.setConfig('scrollable',{
         x:false,
         y:true
     });
}
```

Do this on your beforerender.

No way to make it work on firefox without scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you, the "firefox only" solution is perfect.The first solution it is not working on chrome, there is some weird behaviour with the scroll (probably a conflict between the two scroll)

Comment: perfect, lets see the next time